# How to set the options of select dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I have a combo-box which works as a filter for a column. On changing any value in the column, I want to update the options in the combo-box.
obj.default gives me the old value of the changed field in the column.

```
function valueChange(obj) {
        var optionsArray = document.getElementById('filter').options;
        for (var index = 0; index < optionsArray.length; index++) {
            if (optionsArray[index].value == obj.defaultValue) {
                optionsArray[index].value = new Option(obj.value, obj.value);
            }
        }
    }
```

`optionsArray` is getting populating correctly. How to set back `optionsArray` back to the element's option?

Comment: `optionsArray[index].value = new Option(obj.value, obj.value);` looks wrong. And I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @epascarello I have a combo-box which works as a filter for a column. On changing any value in the column, I want to update the options in the combo-box such that the option corresponding to the old value gets updated to the new value of the field.

Comment: Is {for (var index = 0; index < options.length; index++)} okay? i guess, it should be {for (var index = 0; index < optionsArray.length; index++)}

Comment: @sarwar026 oops.. Typo.. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have the select in html

```
<select id="example-select"></select>
```

This is how we can add option

```
var selectexample = document.getElementById("example-select");
selectexample.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
```

Comment: How to remove any existing option ?

Comment: while (selectElemRef.length> 0) {
    selectElemRef.remove(0);
}

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById('filter').add(new Option(obj.value, obj.value),null);
```

To remove, say the ith option

```
document.getElementById('filter').remove(i);
```